# Как сверстать такой футер с помощью флексов?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хотелось бы понять как решить такую казалось бы тривиальную задачу как верстка данного футера. Я так понял нужно разделить его на footer__top и footer__bottom, но как распределить нижнюю часть? Ведь justify-content тут точно не поможет, так как распределение тут не ровное. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я дам вам такой совет... найти хорошую статью про flex и внимательно ее прочитать и разобраться во всех тонкостях. Ваша задача решается тривиально, если вы действительно знали бы все нюансы модуля flex (а именно базовый размер, flex-grow и flex-shrink).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.footer__bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.footer__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.footer__item {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer__bottom">
    <div class="footer__wrapper">
        <div class="footer__item">2010</div>
        <div class="footer__item">Политика конфиденциальности</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer__item">Создание сайтов</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Вариантов много, но можно сделать и так

Answer (score 0):

Дату и политику оберни еще в один div :) и внутри этого div пропиши margin нужный или этому div назначь еще display: flex и распредели его с помощью justify-content, ну и соответственно останется общему bottom тоже justify-content прописать.